# cursor position not at start of placeholder in contentEditable div in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, cursor, microsoft-edge, contenteditable

The cursor at conteneditable div is not start of placeholder while its working fine in chrome and firefox.

The div is autofocused and cursor must show from initial.

[image]

## html

```
<div id="" class="chatInput" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Type something..." autofocus="autofocus"></div>
```

## css

```
.cInput{
padding: 5px 15px;
    color: var(--text-base-volumeone);
    outline: none;
    cursor: text;
    max-height: 32px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 32px;
    font-family: LATORegular;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    transition: border-color 0.25s ease;
    caret-color: var(--caret-color);
    position: relative;
    white-space: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to search about the issue and it looks like a known issue in the MS Edge legacy browser.

Here is a workaround that you can try with the MS Edge legacy browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
[contenteditable=true] {
  position: relative;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  margin: auto;
}

#myDiv {
  border: 1px dashed #AAA;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 16px;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter text here..."></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Output in the MS Edge legacy browser:

[image]

This solution uses the CSS code. We can notice that the cursor is displays little outside the div. If this is not preferable then you may need to use the JavaScript or Jquery to display the cursor on a start position.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/hHLXr/12/) uses JQuery.

Comment: The div is autofocused and cursor must show from beginning and also cursor is not aligining properly with placeholder.

Comment: This is the workaround. I did not find any other way to use CSS to display the cursor at the start. You can try using the JS code to set the cursor position. I suggest you press the [ALT + J] key in the MS Edge legacy browser window and try to provide feedback about this issue to Microsoft. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: If possible for you then avoid using a placeholder and try to show a label instead of it. It may help to avoid the whole issue.